# Profile / Permissions best practices?

Tags: security, permissions

Hello and thank you in advance. I'm curious if anyone has any resources they could point me to for best practices around permissions sets / profiles / etc. The reason for this is because as an administrator I often run into push-back from users (unfortunately I cannot just tell them to deal with it) when requesting new permissions. I've had cases where other admins in the system have simply granted "modify all data" or "customize application" permissions to make a problem go away, which I know is ill advised, but I would like to present any documentation or resource I can to upper management to make my case in situations like this, in case I need some backup other than "because it's obviously a bad practice".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are badly in need of some governance processes. Salesforce released a wonderful Trailhead module about managing change, I'd suggest you take a peek at it. [Managing Change with a Governance Framework](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/app_deployment/app_deployment_governance)

You don't need to go all-in and create a full governance framework, but minimally being able to identify the [large] risks and dangers of granting "modify all data", for instance, will help your company ensure that your business can keep operating while only granting the minimal permissions in the org to accomplish the task.

There are also some wonderful links at the end of the Trailhead page to presentations from Dreamforce about Data and Org Governance Best Practices, etc.

You and your "other admins" need to grasp the potential downstream impact to the business as a whole when changes like these are introduced without any plan, just to satisfy a little pushback from a User.

Food for thought: How do you foresee your CEO / Board of Directors would react to a user who had been granted "modify all data" accidentally deleting or modifying mass amounts of data in the org? (Potentially destroying everyone else's hard work... I suspect that heads would roll. Including your upper management.)

Comment: Thank you Mark, and I completely agree with what you have to say and was just looking for confirmation. Your food for thought is spot on. I'll take a look at the Trailhead presentation and go from there.